# Nodejs Error, [connection.query]

Tags: node.js

i got error in my console , i'm using nodejs, can you help me? Thanks!
[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Sft.png)
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74Sft.png)

Comment: Atleast share your code snippet.

Comment: http://imgur.com/gv40v2C